# Is there any way I could generate an automatic csv file of the CloudTrail events for one day only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

I can use the console to download the entire CloudTrail events 90 days worth of data but was wondering if there is a way (preferably an automated way) to get one day worth of events. Thank you

Comment: CloudTrail log export to S3 + athena is your best bet

Comment: @jellycsc yes, I am planning to use Athena but not sure what query will give me one day worth of data